# SVG: how to use logarithmic scale

Tags: css, svg

I am using SVG to create a bar chart using rectangles.  I want to know how to specify a logarithmic scale.  My research turns up a few links regarding log scale with SVG charts, but none that shows how it's specified.  SVG does have a "scale" attribute but that doesn't do it.

Here's the html code:

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>A sample graph</figcaption>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="chart" width="1000"   height="150" aria-labelledby="title" role="img">

  <title id="title">A bar chart showing information</title>
  <g class="bar">
    <rect width="40" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="45" y="9.5" dy=".35em">FirstItem</text>
  </g>

  <g class="bar">
    <rect width="230" height="19" y="40"></rect>
    <text x="235" y="48" dy=".35em">SecondItem</text>
  </g>

</svg>
</figure>
```

Here is the css code:

```
.bar {
  fill: green;
  height: 21px;
  transition: fill .3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.bar text {
  fill: #555;
}

.chart:hover .bar,
.chart:focus .bar {
  fill: #aaa;
}

.bar:hover,
.bar:focus {
  fill: blue;
}
.bar:hover text,
.bar:focus text {
  fill: blue;
}

figcaption {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

My question is how to specify a logarithmic scale in the code above.  Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to specify a logarithmic scale as such. You just have to draw the bars at the size they should be on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Peter.  Given the lack of response up until now, I had also concluded that SVG has no way of calculating a log scale so I have to supply the data values calculated as log.  Thanks again.